# boost::shared_ptr and nullptr in default template function argument

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

So, here is my class and its function:

```
template <class T>
class cResourceManager
{
public:
    bool add(const std::string & key, boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr = nullptr); 
private:
    std::map <const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<T> > resources;
};

template <class T>
bool cResourceManager<T>::add(const std::string & key, boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr)
{
    if (resources.find(key) == resources.end())
    {
        if(ptr != nullptr) //we have the object
        {
            resources.insert(std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<T>>(key, ptr));
        return true;
    }
    else //we need to load object using sfml loadFromFile
    {
        T tempResource;
        tempResource.loadFromFile(key);
        resources.insert(std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<T>>(key, new T(tempResource)));
        if(resources[key] == nullptr) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
}
```

That class is in static library, it compliles without problem. However, when I use it in normal application:

```
cResourceManager<sf::Texture> resourceManager;
resourceManager.add("1.PNG");
```

I get error: 
**error: default argument for parameter of type ‘boost::shared_ptr’ has type ‘std::nullptr_t’**

I have no idea what's wrong here, can't shared_ptr have nullptr value? 
I use g++ 4.7 with -std=c++11

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Boost::shared_ptr will support constructor from std::nullptr_t since version 1.53.

Answer (score 2):

this will works with std::shared_ptr instead of boost::shared_ptr I think

Comment: Are shared_ptr now in c++11 standard? And the second question, do boost::shared_ptr have some kind of nullptr keyword?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Members , `boost::shared_ptr` cannot be initialized by a null pointer constant because for the pointer-taking constructor, it is templated by `Y*` where `Y` is a template parameter. A conversion of a null pointer constant to `Y*` is not considered when deducing `Y*`, so that constructor will have a deduction failure and is ignored when passing `nullptr`.

But `std::shared_ptr` can accept it because it has a `std::nullptr_t` overload, so if you want, you can switch.

Note that passing `nullptr` is different from passing a null pointer like `(T*)nullptr`. The latter won't use a `constexpr` constructor but the former will (among other differences). So in the former case if your pointer is a namespace scope variable, it has constant initialization and will not induce initialization races with namespace scope objects in other translation units.

Comment: Thanks! So i will switch to std::shared_ptr

Comment: @user1873947 alternatively you can pass a default constructed `boost::shared_ptr` or in C++11 (which is a precondition to using `std::shared_ptr` anyway) you can just pass `{}` as the function argument, if you want to avoid changing all instances of `boost::shared_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I will switch completely to std::shared_ptr. However, whats the file with std::shared_ptr declaration? I can't find it and i get "std::shared_ptr’ has not been declared"