# Using default parameters when using boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have boost `shared_ptr` as a parameter to function, i would like this parameter to have some default value.

```
void foo(boost::shared_ptr<myclass> ptr = nullptr);
```

because ptr is not a pointer, but a class..

so what can i do ?

i found a similar question :
[boost::shared_ptr and nullptr in default template function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787103/boostshared-ptr-and-nullptr-in-default-template-function-argument)

But the solution there is just to switch to `std::shared_ptr`, but i can't do it

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly ok to initialize `boost::shared_ptr` with `nullptr`. It has a special constructor for this:

```
#if !defined( BOOST_NO_CXX11_NULLPTR )
shared_ptr( boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t ) BOOST_NOEXCEPT : px( 0 ), pn() // never throws
{
}
#endif
```

(`boost::detail::sp_nullptr_t` resolves to `nullptr_t` in a portable manner)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `nullptr` you must be using C++11, so you should be able to do this:

```
void foo(boost::shared_ptr<myclass> ptr = {});
```

That makes the default argument a default-constructed `shared_ptr`, which is the same as one initialized with `nullptr`.  It requires your compiler to support uniform initialization syntax, instead of requiring your Boost version to support constructing `shared_ptr` from `nullptr_t`.

If your compiler can't handle that then use ForEveR's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply?

```
void foo(boost::shared_ptr<myclass> ptr = boost::shared_ptr<myclass>());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not "being class" but that the involved constructor is explicit. And your form would require implicit conversion. You can work it around using an explicit form: `boost::shared_ptr<myclass>(nullptr)` or  `boost::shared_ptr<myclass>()`, whichever is supported for your version.